# Automation task in ci/cd release - retry failed tests

Tags: azure, automation, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a task of automation that include number of tests that running by category in ci/cd.
I'm trying to find something that I can set if certain tests or max tests fail then it will try to run them again before the task fails.
for now i have something like that in my code, any idea?

i working with VSTS (Azure - pipelines release).

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Visual Studio Test task, the task has a built-in feature: `Rerun failed tests`.

[image]

According to your needs, you can specify `rerunType`(Do not rerun if test failures exceed specified threshold). You can specify % failures with `basedOnTestFailurePercentage` or # of failed tests as a threshold with `basedOnTestFailureCount`.